# VBA Excel - Add same value to columns in different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Just want to ask if how can I shorten the codes below? The codes work fine, but I just want to know if there is a way to shorten it since I'll be using the codes in `N-Q1` sheet in other quarter sheets (N-Q1, N-Q2, N-Q3, N-Q4, JK-Q1, etc.). Note that, the `quarter sheets` have the **same structure or column** (column `16`) to be updated, while the `STUDENTS_INFO` sheet is in column `20`.

**STUDENTS INFO** sheets:

```
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("STUDENTS_INFO")
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        
    For r = 9 To lastRow
        
        If ws.Cells(r, 3) = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K11").value) Then
            If ws.Cells(r, 20) = "0" Or ws.Cells(r, 20) = "" Then
                ws.Cells(r, 20) = "1"
                Debug.Print "STUDENTS: " & ws.Cells(r, 3) & "  Verified!"
            Else
                Debug.Print "STUDENTS: " & ws.Cells(r, 3) & "  Already Verified!"
            End If
        End If
    
    Next r
```

**N-Q1** code: **Quarter Sheets** (N-Q1, N-Q2, N-Q3, N-Q4, JK-Q1, etc.)

```
    grd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K16").value
    qrt = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K17").value)
            
    If grd = "Nursery" Then
        ws_output = "N" + "-" + qrt
    ElseIf grd = "Junior Kinder" Then
        ws_output = "JK" + "-" + qrt
    ElseIf grd = "Senior Kinder" Then
        ws_output = "SK" + "-" + qrt
    End If
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws_output)
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        
    For s = 9 To lastRow
        
        If ws.Cells(s, 3) = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K11").value) Then
            If ws.Cells(s, 16) = "0" Or ws.Cells(r, 16) = "" Then
                ws.Cells(s, 16) = "1"
                Debug.Print "GRADES: " & ws.Cells(s, 3) & "  Verified!"
            Else
                Debug.Print "GRADES: " & ws.Cells(s, 3) & "  Already Verified!"
            End If
        End If
    
    Next s
```

Note that, this code will only work depends on the value of `grd` and `qrt`.

I'm thinking of using the code below as a start.

```
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("STUDENTS_INFO", "N-Q1", "N-Q2", "N-Q3", "N-Q4", "N-D", _
"JK-Q1", "JK-Q2", "JK-Q3", "JK-Q4", "JK-D", "SK-Q1", "SK-Q2", "SK-Q3", "SK-Q4", "SK-D"))
    
        With ws.Cells(8, 3).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter 2, LRN
            ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        End With

Next ws
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the code below for the solution that I came up. Thank you!

```
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("N-Q1", "N-Q2", "N-Q3", "N-Q4", "N-D", _
    "JK-Q1", "JK-Q2", "JK-Q3", "JK-Q4", "JK-D", "SK-Q1", "SK-Q2", "SK-Q3", "SK-Q4", "SK-D"))
    
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        
    For r = 9 To lastRow
        
        If ws.Cells(r, 3) = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K11").value) Then
            If ws.Cells(r, 16) = "0" Or ws.Cells(r, 16) = "" Then
                ws.Cells(r, 16) = "1"
                Debug.Print "STUDENTS: " & ws.Cells(r, 3) & "  Verified!"
            Else
                Debug.Print "STUDENTS: " & ws.Cells(r, 3) & "  Already Verified!"
            End If
        End If
    
    Next r
    
    Next ws
```