# VBA Excel - Update cell value after using an AutoFilter

Tags: excel, vba

This is a follow-up question of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66594947/vba-excel-add-same-value-to-columns-in-different-sheet). May I ask if it is possible to update a cell value after using an **Autofilter**? So, the flow that I'm thinking of is it will filter the data then update the `P9` cell wherein this is the first-row result of the filter, with the value of `1`.

Below is the code that I'm trying to modify. This code is similar to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65949121/15080594) but this time I need to update it rather than delete it.

```
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("N-Q1", "N-Q2", "N-Q3", "N-Q4", "N-D", _
"JK-Q1", "JK-Q2", "JK-Q3", "JK-Q4", "JK-D", "SK-Q1", "SK-Q2", "SK-Q3", "SK-Q4", "SK-D"))    
   With ws.Cells(8, 3).CurrentRegion
     .AutoFilter 2, LRN
     ws.AutoFilterMode = False
   End With         
Next ws
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that I made

```
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("N-Q1", "N-Q2", "N-Q3", "N-Q4", "N-D", _
    "JK-Q1", "JK-Q2", "JK-Q3", "JK-Q4", "JK-D", "SK-Q1", "SK-Q2", "SK-Q3", "SK-Q4", "SK-D"))
    
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        
    For r = 9 To lastRow
        
        If ws.Cells(r, 3) = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K11").value) Then
            If ws.Cells(r, 16) = "0" Or ws.Cells(r, 16) = "" Then
                ws.Cells(r, 16) = "1"
                Debug.Print "STUDENTS: " & ws.Cells(r, 3) & "  Verified!"
            Else
                Debug.Print "STUDENTS: " & ws.Cells(r, 3) & "  Already Verified!"
            End If
        End If
    
    Next r
    
    Next ws
```